# AWS SDK for PHP - No load balancers are showing

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

I am using the AWS SDK for PHP to query a load balancer for all of its healthy instances. I tried using the [describeInstanceHealth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.ElasticLoadBalancing.ElasticLoadBalancingClient.html#_describeInstanceHealth) method to get all of the healthy instances from my ELB, only to find that it said there was no active load balancer with the name I supplied.

I then decided to use [describeLoadBalancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.ElasticLoadBalancing.ElasticLoadBalancingClient.html#_describeLoadBalancers) to see what name it used internally, only to find that the function is returning no load balancers at all. I have 3 active load balancers that are being used as I type this.

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
<?php
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\ElasticLoadBalancing\ElasticLoadBalancingClient;
...
$client = ElasticLoadBalancingClient::factory([
    'key'    => env('ACCESS_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SECRET'),
    'region' => env('REGION')
]);

$result = $client->describeLoadBalancers();
var_dump($result);
```

The output I get is the following:

```
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)#106 (2) { 
    ["structure":protected]=> NULL ["data":protected]=> array(2) {
        ["LoadBalancerDescriptions"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["ResponseMetadata"]=> array(1) { 
            ["RequestId"]=> string(36) "e6e7b0a4-7880-11e7-bb72-995ab0ed2a69" 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `LoadBalancerDescriptions` key has an empty array, when it should contain a description of all active load balancers.

My guess is that something is not configured correctly with the IAM roles and my user is not able to see the load balancers, but I don't know of a way to attach the user/access key that I am using to the load balancers.

How can I make the load balancers visible to the API calls I am making?

I am using PHP 5.6.31.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right region?

Comment: My ELBs are listed under US West (Oregon) and the availability zones are `us-west-2a`, `us-west-2b`, and `us-west-2c`. The region I am using is `us-west-2`, which looks correct to me.

Comment: I don't think its an IAM issue, because usually you'd get back a Not authorized message

Comment: I'd var dump $client just to be sure its what you expect. Don't post it on here obviously.

Comment: Everything in $client looks fine as far as I can tell. Anything special I should be paying attention to?

Comment: The region... I'm still not convinced ;)  Have you tried using the AWS CLI also? aws elb describe-load-balancers

Comment: Found the issue--ELB supports two types of load balancers: Classic and Application. Mine are Application, which is only supported by v2 and up of the SDK (I am using v1)

Comment: You should answer your own question. It's a good answer.

Comment: Will do once I verify using the newer version of the SDK solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out ELB supports two types of load balancers: Classic and Application. The AWS SDK V1 does not support application load balancers. I had to upgrade the SDK and use [describeTargetHealth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-elasticloadbalancingv2-2015-12-01.html#describetargethealth) to get the instance IDs for each instance in the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out by using the ELBv2 API and the `describeTargetHealth` method.